# Self Join in MS access returns too many record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in **2013 MS acces**s that has civilian names with the fields :
 First_Name (text), Last_name(text), ID_no(primary key), Gender(text), Continent(text)(as in the continent they live in), Sector_area(text).

the table is called People. to self join it so that people who are in the same continent pop up I was taught to say,

```
SELECT A.First_Name AS Name1, B.First_Name AS Name2, A.Continent
FROM People AS A, People AS B
WHERE A.ID_No <> B.ID_No
AND A.Continent = B.Continent
ORDER BY A.Continent;
```

the table only has 70 records but when the sql is run i get 760 records. the script creates a list of combinations of names as Name1 and Name2.

How do I stop this combination making and only getting less records?

[image]

Comment: Learn how to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self join is not the solution. GROUP By should be.

```
select FirstName, LastName, Continent from
People
group by FirstName, LastName, Continent
order by Continent, LastName

or

select FirstName, LastName from
People
where Continent = 'Africa'
group by FirstName, LastName
order by LastName
```

Comment: Yep, this works. but on w3 schools, says do a Self Join on the tutorial, i literally copy and pasted the syntax. Thanks for a simpler way. Here's the link to the W3 page: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp